# Trouble preserving $_GET variables

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I want to redirect from /gallery/X to gallery.php?category=X

But when I actually goto the address, my old $_GET variable 'category' is transformed into the form:

```
$_GET['category'] = "X.php/X"
```

This is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ /gallery.php?category=$1 [L]
```

I am very bad at RegEx and no almost nothing about .htaccess.  I have been trying to play around with this rewrite rule to preserve the $_GET variables, but nothing I do seem to work.  What am I supposed to do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your rules around:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ /gallery.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Also, add `QSA` to your action, `[L,QSA]`. This appends the query string during the redirect, so it should keep your previous data.

**Explanation:**

Your rewrites need to be in a specific order because the `[L]` option is like making a completely new request to the server. So, when your request for `gallery/X` came in, it rewrote your request to `/gallery.php?category=X`. When this page was requested by the server, it matched your first rule, which means it was being seen as `X.php/X` which was then being returned to the original request as the extra `$1`.

Sounds confusing but I think that's what was going on.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I'm still confused how changing the order and adding QSA did that, would you mind explaining what was happening to the request so I can understand htaccess a little better?

Comment: Added an explanation. I think that's what was happening. Glad it worked!